# Finding relevant attributes in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a model with 30 attributes. but those attributes can be grouped in 2 groups.

For example I have:

```
string:title
string:text
...
```

and

```
string:title_old
string:text_old
...
```

I want to be able: When I check `title` attribute at the same time to check the `title_old` attribute. Can I perform that with a loop if I make an array of the 15 first strings or I should write hard coded if statements

Final goal:

```
        [
          {
             :name => :title,
             :y => 1 (constant),
             :color=> red, (if title_old == "something" color = red else color = green)
          },
          {
             :name=> :text,
             :y => 1 (constant)
             :color => red (if text_old == "something" color = red else color = green)
          },
          .... (all other 13 attributes)
       ]
```

Comment: you need to save back this stuff or just get a json-like/hash representation?

Comment: No just get the representation to create a graph!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your model:

```
class MyModel < AR::Base
  def attributize
    attrs = self.attributes.except(:created_at, :updated_at).reject{ |attr, val| attr =~ /.*_old/ && !val }
    attrs.inject([]) do |arr, (attr, val)|
      arr << { :name => attr, :y => 1, :color => (self.send("#{attr}_old") == "something" ? "red" : "green") }
    end
  end
end
```

usage:

```
my_object = MyModel.last
my_object.attributize
```

Comment: If I want to exclude another attribute? `attrs = self.attributes.reject{ |attr, val| attr =~ /.*_old/ }` Can you please extend that to exclude created_at, updated_at?

Comment: Can I also do not accept all attr which have val =false ? I did `arr << { :name => attr, :y => 1, :color => (self.send("#{attr}_old") == "something" ? "red" : "green") if val = true` but I get `undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass` .Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple example:

```
class MyModel
  def identify_color
    if send("#{name}_old".to_sym) == "something"
      'red'
    else
      'green'
    end
  end
end

MyModel.all.collect do |instance|
  attrs = instance.attributes
  attrs.merge!('color' => identify_color)
  attrs
end
```

Add some rescue at will, but it can be done in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[
 :title,
 ..,
 ..
 :description
].map do |attr|
  {
    :name => attr,
    :y => 1 (constant),
    :color=> (read_attribute("#{attr}_old") == "something") ? "red" : "green"
  }  
end
```

PS: Naming an attribute `text` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

use state_machine, that way your logic will be in one place with a clear dsl.  https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine